# ForeignKey dependencies in Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm using Django 1.6.4.

I have a `Section` model that has a ManyToMany relationship with a `TimePeriod` model. I also have a `Question` model that has a ForeignKey relationship with the `Section` model and the `TimePeriod` model.

What I'd like to do is auto-filter the `Section` part of the `Question` form to valid `Sections` when a given `TimePeriod` is selected.

For example, if the 2014 `TimePeriod` contains Section1 and Section2, but the 2013 `TimePeriod` contains Section2 and Section3, I only want to display Section2 and Section3 in the `Section` dropdown when 2013 is selected and Section1 and Section2 when 2014 is selected.

First, are there any packages that have been created that do this out of the box? If not, what do I have to do to set this up manually?

Thanks!

Model definitions were requested. They're pretty simple:

#### section.py

```
class Section(TimeStampedModel):
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'nps'
        ordering = ('number',)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    time_period = models.ManyToManyField('TimePeriod',
                                         related_name='sections')
```

#### timeperiod.py

```
class TimePeriod(TimeStampedModel, TimeFramedModel):
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'nps'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

#### question.py

```
class Question(TimeStampedModel):
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'nps'
        unique_together = ('time_period', 'number',)

    time_period = models.ForeignKey('TimePeriod',
                                    related_name='questions')
    section = models.ForeignKey('Section', related_name='questions')
    page = models.IntegerField()
    number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    name = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)
```

Comment: Could you show the model definitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing it as validation on the admin form in the `clean()` method.